# Merge four tables from MySQL and show only rows that satisfy condition in Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I have four tables say table1, table2, table3, table4 in MySQL, which have identical columns ID, Description, Quantity, Status, Remarks.

I am trying to merge/combine rows of all four tables that have the status column as "DEL" and this data should be shown in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about exporting the result into Excel, but I assume it's pretty easy and you can google it.

To combine the results simply use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE status = 'DEL'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE status = 'DEL'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE status = 'DEL'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM Table4 WHERE status = 'DEL'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate..I wrote the query directly into excel. Using the ribbon DATA-->From Other Source-->MS Query I got into the query editor and then the rest you know.